# Reconfiguring volume up and down buttons?

Tags: tasker, volume-control, buttons, locale

A few days ago, I came to know about apps such as Tasker and Locale. Today, I have purchased the Tasker app from Google Play. I have spent around more than an hour, going around and exploring the app.

I didn't find any option that would reconfigure/reprogram the volume up and down buttons (whereas camera button can be). Instead of having various different gestures and shakes to trigger/change/alter/start something, it would be lot more easier to just press the volume up and down buttons (or may be even different binary combinations of these two buttons).

Is it possible to reconfigure these buttons on automation app such as Tasker and Locale?

Answer (score 3):

For Android 4.3 and above, I would recommend using [Auto-Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) by joaomgcd.

> It allows you to
>   create a series of input actions, including physical button presses
>   and various taps and swipes, to emulate some sort of macro sequence
>   that can be executed inside any app of your choosing. And if you
>   happen to be rooted, AutoInput has a Root feature that can literally
>   simulate any input on your phone. "[Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/15/autoinput-joaomgcd-tasker-plugin-automating-taps-swipes-text-entries/)"

So in essence you can use the Volume up and Down buttons to do anything you want and to also make them do different things within different apps.

**Here are some links to help you get going:**

[AutoInput](http://joaoapps.com/autoinput/)

[Autoinput App Projects](http://forum.joaoapps.com/index.php?resources/categories/autoinput.11/)

**Examples of Use of Volume Buttons:**

[Double Click Volume Up in Chrome To Share Page](http://forum.joaoapps.com/index.php?resources/double-click-volume-up-in-chrome-to-share-page.76/) - 
*Learn how to react to the volume keys so that you can share your currently opened web page in Chrome*

[Volumecomboskip](http://tasker.wikidot.com/volumecomboskip) - Tasker Profile that Incorporates The Volume up and Down Button To skip songs

Comment: I personally see two problems with this answer. 1) The question was posted in 2012 and while OP didn't mention the Android version, it is safe to assume that the Android version used by OP at that moment was below 4.3 and AutoInput supports only 4.3 and above version. But that's not enough for me to vote down. 2) You've not mentioned **how to** use AutoInput to achieve the goal. I'm willing to revoke my downvote and appreciate your answer **if you mention the detailed usage of that app** for the  goal.

Comment: @Firelord I Realised that it was from 2012, and that the user would have have below 4.3, but I answered for the current times (2015) so people who would find this question would at least have any up to date answer even though the question was old. I personally answered for newcomers on this question, not the actually asker this time because the question was old. I will post the instructions today.

Comment: @Firelord I Have given example, but cannot give a detailed walkthrough as I cant use the app due to my android version. I would rather not plagiaris some elses step-by-step walkthrough. I have add examples. This is an answer to you above comment ^^